# Fill shower trap when it gets empty with water pressure

Tags: shower, water-pressure

I have a problem that i want to solve with a temporary fix:

When somebody flushes toilet in the apartment house, my shower drain is emptied.

I bough some tube and a water bottle and connected the tube to the bottle. Filled the bottle with water and put other end of the tube to shower trap - the problem is the water is still constantly running into the trap. I wanted it to stop when the end of the tube is in the water. How can i achieve this?

[image: illustrating picture]

Comment: First, check to make sure that none of the plumbing vent pipes are blocked ir plugged.

Comment: Some kind of mini float-valve or ball-valve? Or just cure the actual problem with an air-admittance valve on the shower drain?

Comment: Please, just give coherent, good answers that address the problem and make sense. Float valves and water bottles with tubes are not a solution to a real problem. These answers people give  are just dreams and ideas that have no merit or make any sense. Isherwood had the only statement that made any sense.  I can't comment on my own solution which is just a continuation of his statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility but I'm not sure it would work in practice.

You'd need a container which could be sealed so that water will flow out the bottom when the end of the hose is uncovered, but when the cap on the container is secured a low pressure will develop on top of the water in the container. This is the principle used for animal water bowls which replenish a tray from an inverted container.

I can imagine a plastic jerrican with a hose coming from the bottom. Fill it and the water would fill the tube and start flowing. Then screw on the sealing cap and a 'partial vacuum' will develop above the water. When the pressure goes down to a certain level the water flow will stop.

When the trap is drained and the end of the hose exposed, bubbles of air may move up in the tube and increase the pressure above the water in the sealed container. The diameter of the hose is critical--it must be large enough for bubbles of air to move upward through the water in the tube all the way to the container.

You may  find that adding detergent to the water in the reservoir would enable bubbles to form and move up the tube when the end is uncovered. The detergent lowers the surface tension of the water and allows bubbles to move up the tube.

Answer (score 1):

That drain stack either does not have a vent or the vent is plugged with something. Check to see where the drain piping above the toilet goes. It should be tied to a vent stack that eventually penetrates the roof.A stack that is not vented will suck air from wherever it can and the shower is that place. Contact the apartment building owner and tell him your problem. Once the shower drain trap is sucked dry the sewer gases can run up that drain line, and come out into your apartment. You will have smells and flammable gases in your place.